# Function to count names on a list?

Tags: r, function

Hey guys I am working on an R exercise and I have the following problem: basically I have a data set with names of several people that got a callback for a job, and I am being asked what are the most and less frequent names that appear in this dataset. Do you guys know any function in R that does this?

Comment: Can you show few lines of data

Comment: Here are some lines of the data.
2 Kristen female white 0
3 Lakisha female black 0
4 Latonya female black 0
5 Carrie female white 0
6 Jay male white 0
7 Jill female white 0
8 Kenya female black 0
9 Latonya female black 0
10 Tyrone male black 0
11 Aisha female black 0
12 Allison female white 0
13 Aisha female black 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a `list`, then `unlist` and get the frequency with `table`

```
out <- table(unlist(lst1))
```

If it is a data.frame with column named 'Name'

```
out <- table(df1$Name)
```

and then get the max, and min 'names'  based on the index

```
names(out)[which.min(out)]
names(out)[which.max(out)]
```

If there are ties and want to get all the names, then use `==`

```
names(out)[out == min(out)]
names(out)[out == max(out)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Allison", "Kristen", "Lakisha", "Latonya", 
"Carrie", "Jay", "Jill", "Kenya", "Latonya", "Tyrone", "Aisha", 
"Allison", "Aisha"), Sex = c("female", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", 
"female", "female"), Race = c("white", "white", "black", "black", 
"white", "white", "white", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"white", "black"), v1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), v2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```